# Scripting Adobe Illustrator using Python

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to automate operations on .ai file using python so that my application can use it. I came across a basic tutorial on using win32com package to refer Adobe Illustrator.

I would like to know if it is possible to write further classes in python to mimic vbscript or javascript scripting support provided by Adobe Illustrator.

Is there a possibility to achieve this, better to stick with  given scripting support like javascript or vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to automate Illustrator using Python. Your best bet is to look at the VB Script examples on this page and modify the code to work in Python :

[Illustrator Scripting](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html)

You can control about 95% of Illustrator using Python. For that last 5%, you'll have to create an action inside Illustrator and call that action from inside your Python app.
Online documentation for Python->Illustrator scripting is really scarce so it can be a little frustrating sometimes, but it's possible and very effective.